# Is there a pythonic way to iterate a dictionary of ranges to build new dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, iterator

Supposing that a have this dict with the keys and some range:

```
d = {"x": (0, 2), "y": (2, 4)}
```

I need to create dicts using the range above, I will get:

```
>>> keys = [k for k,v in d.items()]
>>> 
>>> def newDict(keys,array):
...     return dict(zip(keys,array))
... 
>>> for i in range(0,2):
...     for j in range(2,4):
...         dd = newDict(keys, [i,j])
...         print (dd)
... 
{'x': 0, 'y': 2}
{'x': 0, 'y': 3}
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
{'x': 1, 'y': 3}
```

My doubt is how to iterate change the key **using the ranges** and create a new dicts in a more pythonic way.

Supposing the I add more one key **z**:

```
d = {"x": (0, 2), "y": (2, 4), "z": (3, 5)}
```

So, I will need to add a more for loop nested. Is there another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can replace your nested loops with a single `itertools.product` call.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> p = product(*([(k, v) for v in range(*V)] for k, V in d.items()))
>>> list(map(dict, p))
[{'x': 0, 'y': 2}, {'x': 0, 'y': 3}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}]
```

How it works -

1. For each key : value pair (e.g., `"x": (0, 2)`), flatten it to form a list of tuples (e.g., `[("x", 0), ("x", 1)]`). You get one list for each pair
2. Take the cartesian `product`. You get a iterator of lists of tuples
3. For each iterator, convert the list of tuples to a dictionary using `map`
4. Listify the entire result

Answer (score 2):

First, store your ranges directly as range objects, rather than as endpoints:

```
>>> d = {'x': (0, 2), 'y': (2, 4), 'z': (3, 5)}
>>> d = {k: range(*v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Now you have simple list comprehension available:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [dict(zip(d, p)) for p in product(*d.values())]
[{'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
 {'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 4},
 {'x': 0, 'y': 3, 'z': 3},
 {'x': 0, 'y': 3, 'z': 4},
 {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
 {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 4},
 {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 3},
 {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 4}]
```